# Let $G$ be a multiplicative group of all positive real numbers and $\Bbb R$ be the additive group of all real numbers. Is $G\le\Bbb R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a multiplicative group of all positive real numbers and  $\mathbb R$ be the additive group of all real numbers. Is $G$ a subgroup of  $\mathbb R$?

In this problem, I understand that $G$ is a subset of  $\mathbb R$, kindly guide me to proceed further to reach the conclusion.

Thank you.

Comment: That is a non-standard definition of $\Bbb R$. $\Bbb R$ is a field, not a group; it has multiplication as well as addition. You should call your $\Bbb R$ something else.

Comment: The two groups are **isomorphic** using logarithms. Subgroup no. Any additive subgroup of $\,\mathbb{R}\,$ must contain $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations aside, the identity $e_\mathcal{H}$ of a subgroup $\mathcal{H}$ of a group $\mathcal{G}$ is always $e_\mathcal{G}$, that of the group $\mathcal{G}$. We have $e_\mathcal{G}e_\mathcal{H}=e_\mathcal{H}=e_\mathcal{H}e_\mathcal{H}$, so, multiplying on the right by $e_\mathcal{H}^{-1}$, we get $e_\mathcal{G}=e_\mathcal{H}$.

The identity of your group $G$ is $1$, whereas that of $\Bbb R$ is $0$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, See my comment to the OP.

Answer (score 5):

A subgroup of a group must have the same operation as the group (You can refer to the definition given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) ). So in this case $G$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ because operations are different.